# Cordova: Should I use php or node.js to fetch database?

Tags: php, android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on a Cordova project. I know that I can use either PHP or node.js to interact with mysql database.

I am curious to know that which approach is best; Should I use PHP or node.js to interact with MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use whatever you are confortable with.
I personally build Cordova apps with AngularJS (frontend) and NodeJS (backend).
This choice, for me, is the best as I mostly build real time applications using socket.io as a communication channel.

I became a fan of NodeJS, JavaScript in general, lately, so I'll choose this over PHP anytime. I think that NodeJS it's more flexible and offers you access to a lot more tools & libraries than PHP.

To connect to mysql with NodeJS, you have this active maintained module: [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

If your concern is performance, have a look at this topic: [node.js MySQL performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014256/node-js-mysql-performance)

Comment: Perfect Answer...
Thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts. Its really useful to me.