# NodeJS much slower than PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, apache, performance

I run a tiny scale web server under Apache + PHP + MySQL at the moment and would like to explore the option of using NodeJS instead. The server literally does two things:

1. Serve some static files (HTML/CSS/image resources etc)
2. Query the database (select and insert only, no update or delete)

However, I'm running into some performance issue and I'm trying to figure out where the problem is. To isolate the problem, I've created a minimal NodeJS app, which runs a query against MySQL and return 50 rows of data as JSON. Below is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createPool({
    host: <host>,
    user: <user>,
    password: <password>,
    database: <database>,
    debug: false
});

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    var sql = 'SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table';
    db.query(sql, function (error, rows, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(rows);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Running on port 3000.");
});
```

By using ApacheBench to fire 1000 requests at a concurrency level of 1 (in order not to disadvantage the single-threaded Node app), the result is as follows:

```
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   10.377 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      3057000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2829000 bytes
Requests per second:    96.37 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       10.377 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       10.377 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          287.69 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

As a comparison, below is my code in PHP:

```
<?php

    $hostname = <host>;
    $username = <user>;
    $password = <password>;
    $database = <database>;

    try {
        $db_handler = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception('[ERROR] Unable to connect to the database.');
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table';
    $statement = $db_handler->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $statement->execute();
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);

    $db_handler = null;

?>
```

And the result from ApacheBench:

```
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   6.726 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      3023000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2829000 bytes
Requests per second:    148.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       6.726 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       6.726 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          438.92 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

From the above result, it is observed that PHP is much faster than NodeJS. The discrepancy is even wider if a more complex query is fired (the difference could be 20 times, like 20ms vs 400ms), or if the concurrency level is increased.

I've tried to add up to 4 workers (I'm running the server on Raspberry Pi 2 which has 4 cores) to the Node app and see if it helps, unfortunately it is still not close to the result in PHP. Could you please advise what I might have done wrong? Or NodeJS is just not a good pick for what I'm trying to achieve?

**[EDITED]**

Thanks a lot for all your comments. Seems like most people suspect that the problem is caused by the NodeJS MySQL driver. I've also done a bit more testing to make sure if that's the case, and I accidentally found something really interesting.

By running the same Node app in another PC (Core 2 Duo E7200), but connecting to the same MySQL on Raspberry Pi, the result is in fact quite decent:

```
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   2.705 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      3057000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2829000 bytes
Requests per second:    369.71 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2.705 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.705 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1103.72 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

And as a comparison, I've also run an Apache server on that PC, connecting to the same MySQL on Raspberry Pi, and below is the result:

```
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   6.297 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      3034000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2829000 bytes
Requests per second:    158.80 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       6.297 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       6.297 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          470.50 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

As a summary, below is the result I've gotten so far. Only the web server part is different, while the database is always MySQL on Raspberry Pi:

```
Server      Time Taken
Node (Pi)   10.337s
PHP (Pi)    6.726s
Node (PC)   2.705s
PHP (PC)    6.297s
```

The result for PHP appears to be more or less the same on both server, while that of NodeJS varies a lot. Based on the result above, it appears to me that NodeJS is more sensitive to CPU performance, or in another words CPU intensive? (The NodeJS version I'm using is v6.9.4, just FYI)

Comment: You are fetching data from Mysql with Nodejs and PHP , my experience with mysql /nodejs is not good because of Nodejs Mysql Driver.  similar problem with PHP and MongoDB.

Comment: I'd play around with some different drivers to see if you can get an improvement

Comment: Nodejs and Mysql combination is not good and similar with PHP and MongoDB

Comment: FWIW the `mysql` module is known to be slow. Try `mysql2` instead.

Comment: NodeJS is better at handling many concurrent requests so you will most likely only see a performance improvement when the app is handling a lot of traffic.

Comment: Also, you're using a compression middleware in the node example, but it's not clear if compression is also being used in the PHP scenario. Lastly, you might benchmark against the node core http server (instead of Express) to get a good idea of how slow Express can be.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your comment. I've edited my question to add a bit more benchmark and comparison. Things are getting a bit more interesting now...

Comment: @mscdex With regards to the compression part, it is turned on for the Apache server. zlib.output_compression = On and zlib.output_compression_level = 9. Thanks for your hint on the Express part, lemme also give a try on that.

Comment: @CLDev please mention the php version also. You are using node v6.9.4 (latest version). Try PHP v7(latest version) also.Then it will be better comparison. The php7 has multi-folds better performance than php5. I have explored and come to know that the node application consumes lot of resource.

Comment: @kaushikkaran Yes I'm using PHP5. I've no doubt that PHP7 will be faster, but I'm actually concerned about the performance on NodeJS, which I'm potentially migrating to. Given that NodeJS is no match to PHP5, the difference when comparing to PHP7 will be even more drastic.

Comment: you creating pool but not limit the connection 
  connectionLimit: 10, limit the connection then check the performance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014256/node-js-mysql-performance

Comment: http://fearby.com/article/how-to-setup-pooled-mysql-connections-in-node-js-that-dont-disconnect/

Comment: @CLDev what I suggest that if you are switching to node, then please increase the RAM and processor of your server. As it consumes comparatively more resources than php.

Comment: @Adiii Thanks for your comment. I've read that SO question before posting mine. Unfortunately it doesn't really help much. In fact on a PC the Node app runs faster than PHP, but on Raspberry Pi it isn't. So it doesn't appear to be a MySQL problem actually. Also, if you look at the documentation, the default connectionLimit is defaulted 10 (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options), I guess I don't have to explicitly specify that?

Comment: yeah default is 10 but u can increase them or u can mysql2

Comment: @kaushikkaran Thanks for your suggestion. I've monitored the CPU and RAM usage of my the node process when I fired the query via ApacheBench, they aren't very high actually. I'll try to do a bit of profiling and see if I can get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: @Adiii The frustrating part is, the setup of the NodeJS app on PC and Raspberry Pi are identical. If it is solely related to the number of connections in the pool, then shouldn't it be slow on PC too? I've tried mysql2 which mscdex has also suggested, the difference is not significant, maybe 10% faster or so but still not close to the performance on PHP.

Comment: What are you after?  Throughput (pages per second) or Latency (ms to finish one page)?  For throughput, you should allow multiple threads - you may find some of the approaches reach 1000/sec.  Your benchmarks seem focused on latency; 10ms is not bad for what you are doing.

Comment: @RickJames In fact both. The background is, I'm migrating my existing PHP stack over to NodeJS. So I want to at least match up the performance. The problem is NodeJS seems to be quite inconsistent, the latency is 2.7ms vs 10.37ms and throughput is 1104Kb vs 288Kb on a PC and Pi respectively. For PHP, despite it can't really outperform the best performance on NodeJS, it is consistently delivering with 6ish ms latency and 400ish Kb throughput, regardless of the platform.. I seriously wonder if NodeJS is such a beast when it comes to constraint in system resources...

Comment: What about [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com)? It's a very popular abstraction layer that makes writing MySQL code a lot easier. You're also using compression on the Node side which could be punishing. I'd remove that and benchmark again.

Comment: @tadman A few people also suggested me to take out the compression middleware and see if it makes things faster, unfortunately it doesn't really help. Besides, I've in fact also turned on gzip for PHP and set the compression level to 9, but it is still faster. I'll give a try at Sequelize and see if it works well. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

> By using ApacheBench to fire 1000 requests at a concurrency level of 1 (in order not to disadvantage the single-threaded Node app)

By limiting concurrency to 1, you're actually taking away node's biggest advantage, which is asynchronous IO. Even though node.js is single-threaded, it will handle other requests while waiting on the db.query call.

Because node is not using system threads for this, but its own lightweight scheduler, it can execute concurrent requests much cheaper than Apache. Apache can be configured in different ways to handle multiple requests (e.g. pre-forking a fixed number of processes or event-driven forking), but once you have a certain number of concurrent requests, things will slow down as requests might have to wait for others to complete, even if those others are doing nothing but waiting for the DB.

So, to conclude, for synchronously executing a single request, yes PHP might be faster; but once you have enough requests which exceed the limit set by Apache's configuration and which is affected also by the size of your machine, you should see node.js being faster overall.

Comment: Hi Bastian. Thanks for your answer. So you are saying, NodeJS might work better if I have a lot of concurrent requests, otherwise Apache + PHP may be a better choice? To give you a bit more background, I was working on a migration from Apache + PHP stack to NodeJS. After the migration, I realized that my API calls take longer time to respond, and as there are very few visitors per day, most of the time the API calls are fired on its own.

Comment: For a single API call, the difference can range from 2 times to 20 times slower (20ms vs 400ms, or for complex ones 1.2s vs 2.4s). So I started off   looking into what might have gone wrong, but so far I don't find anything conclusive.

Comment: @CLDev what mean is that with very many requests, node.js can be more performant on a resource-constraint machine. With your apparently very small number of requests, this advantage of node.js will not be used. However, I would be very surprised if your specific performance problem has anything to do with php and node.js per se -- the drastic 1.2s to 2.4s slowdown indicates another problem elsewhere, even with the less-efficient node mysql driver (rather than mysql2).

Comment: @CLDev For example, Apache does some additional things like caching, which you don't get out of the box in node. I.e. for idempotent requests, such as a repeated GET for the same URL and same query parameters, a well-configured Apache will return a cached version on subsequent calls. In node, it depends on the framework you use, whether you implement your own caching, or you could put an Apache or other webserver in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do some similar testing.

`ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://localhost:8080/` or

`ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://localhost:8080/`

node may crash with error `"Too many connections"`
if modify the code to add `con.end()` after query
node may crash with error `"PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT"`
May need to modify the code and do few more test.

P/S : no error with php.

`ab -n 10000 -c 10000 http://localhost/Php03.php`