# Can node server handle 5000+ requests/sec as Java+Glassfish?

Tags: node.js

I'm not familar with Java servers, but was told with Glassfish, a Java server can handle 5000+ requests/sec.

For node + mysql, according to this test,
[node.js MySQL performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014256/node-js-mysql-performance)
only 137 requests/sec without cluster mode.

So how can node app catch up with Java+Glassfish ?

Comment: To be fair, that's a very old version of Node.js and you're only looking at the first benchmark that was performed. When he ran the test with 10 workers it went up to about 378 requests/sec. With newer versions of Node.js and newer database drivers, I imagine the performance will be even better. But the point of Node.js is that it scales easily just by running a higher number of instances in parallel, while (my understanding is) you cannot do the same with other technologies, or if you can, it is more difficult to configure.

Comment: Also, you say "only 137 requests/sec", but the base case with Apache was 133 requests/sec. None of those benchmarks contain results of running Glassfish, so you're already comparing apples and oranges. You need to run them on the same CPU to get a fair comparison.

Comment: Sorry my question was, how to make node system handle 5000 requests. Let’s say I run 40 node app instances, they are on different ports, guess I need a load balancer? Can I combine node with glassfish ?…

Comment: Typically remote hosting services will handle load-balancing for you, but yes if you want that sort of performance, you need to run node instances in parallel. As for an exact number, that depends on several factors I could only speculate on without actual benchmarks.