# Is it common to set mysql connectionLimit to 100+ to improve performance in node.js app?

Tags: node.js

for mysql driver for node.js, there's a connectionLimit.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
```

Since mysql server max connection limit is 151 (depends on version), can we change connectionLimit to be 150, so the load performance can be great ?

Wondering if there's a benchmark test somewhere.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good option. It is probably better to go the route of clustering your application using the 'cluster' module. NodeJS by default is single-threaded. Here is a good discussion on it, albeit around PHP vs NodeJS. 
[node.js MySQL performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014256/node-js-mysql-performance)